# rewrite react-tag-autocomplete using hooks

Tags: reactjs

How can I rewrite react-tag-autocomplete using hooks? Every example I came across was using .bind(this) keyword for the onAddition method which is the old way of doing it, I want to use react-tag-autocomplete with hooks. I have defined the following:

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState([{ name: "tag1" }, { name: "tag2" }]);




 const handleAddition = (e) => {
    console.log("add");
    setTags([...tags, tag]);
  };



 <ReactTags
            tags={tags}
             ref={reactTags}
              onDelete={handleDelete}
              //onAddition={handleAddition}
              onAddition={(e) => handleAddition(e.target.value)}
                    />
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState([{ name: "tag1" }, { name: "tag2" }]);




 const handleAddition = (tag) => {
    console.log("add");
    setTags([...tags, tag]);
  };



 <ReactTags
            tags={tags}
             ref={reactTags}
              onDelete={handleDelete}
              //onAddition={handleAddition}
              onAddition={(e) => handleAddition(e)}
                    />
```